# how to customize the controls and theme of the jwplayer

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using the following code to play audio files on the browser

this is my javascript

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
                ready: function () {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { "<?php echo $extension ?>": "<?php echo $audiopath ?>" });
                    $(this).jPlayer("play");
                },
                supplied: "<?php echo $extension ?>"
            });
            $("a").click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

How to change the **theme** of the player,and **alignment of control**s?
Actually there is lot of change in jwplayer, this was the code written long back. So i dont want to change tthe jwplayer code according to latest release.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: what ver of jwplayer you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can build a skin. We have a skin SDK available here - http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/